# Rotate Everything On The Z Axis

Tags: animation

i was just wondering if someone could tell me how to rotate everything at the same time on the Z Axis.
https://i.ibb.co/YRfMGGm/adsasd.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parent all the objects to one object and rotate that on the Z axis.

Select all objects with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>, on the last object press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> then choose *Parent to Object*.

Now rotate the last object you selected and everything will rotate with it.